# How to get all the active users (currently logged in) in .NET Core Identity

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I would like to show a table with user name, Email and current active status. Does `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` have such a function to check if a user is active or not?

Controller Code:

```
   [Authorize]
   public class UserController : Controller
   {
       private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
       public UserController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
       {
           _userManager = userManager;
       }
       public IActionResult Index()
       {
           var users = _userManager.Users.ToList();
           return View(users);
       }
   }
```

View Code:

```
        @foreach(var user in Model){
              <tr>
                  <td> @user.UserName </td>
                  <td> @user.Email </td>
                  <td> Currently I dont know </td>
              </tr>
         }
```

[image: Target Table]

Comment: Can you post the method that you are using to bind data?

Comment: I updated my question with Controller and view code. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "active" exactly? You know the last time the user logged in, but how do you define that the user is active? On a side note, you shouldn't be able to show the password because you should not store passwords in the db.

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuser?view=aspnetcore-1.1 there is no active field for User table. If you want to add active column in database then you have to add it in ApplicationUser class.

Comment: Just add a column to the `AspNetUsers` table `LastLogin` (`DateTime`). On each request Get the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan`, add it to the `DateTime.Now` and store the result in the database... That would be if `CookieAuthenticationOptions.SlidingExpiration == true`. Otherwise just check if `AspNetUsers.LastLogin + CookieAuthenticationOptions.ExpireTimeSpan < DateTime.Now`